# Why `tf.train.Optimizer().compute_gradients(loss)` also returns variables not in the subgraph of `loss`?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I'm manually collecting the gradients statistics of the **Multi-Tasking** model, the **graph** of which looks schematically like this:

```
input -> [body_var1 ... body_varN] --> [task1_var1 ... task1_varM] <-- loss_1
                                   \-> [task2_var1 ... task2_varM] <-- loss_2
```

I'm defining a separate optimizer for each loss as follows (the actual code is much complicated, the following is simplified for this question):

```python
# for simplicity, just demonstrate the case with the 1st task
task_index = 1

# here we define the optimizer (create an instance in graph)
loss = losses[task_index]
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer()
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)

# now let's see what it returns
for g, v in grads_and_vars:
    print('  grad:', g, ', var:', v)
```

So, the code above clearly creates a separated optimizer only for the branch of task 1, then we create the gradient computation ops with `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)` and print the vars to which we apply the gradients to.

**Expected results**:

```python
grad: body_var1_grad, var: body_var1    # \
...                                     # --> body vars and gradients
grad: body_varN_grad, var: body_varN    # /
grad: task1_var1_grad, var: task1_var1  # \
...                                     # --> task 1 vars and gradients
grad: task1_var1_grad, var: task1_var1  # /
```

So I'm expecting that the optimizer only contains gradient computing ops for the branch it was applied on (i.e. the branch for 1st task)

**Actual results**

```python
grad: body_var1_grad, var: body_var1    # \
...                                     # --> body vars and gradients
grad: body_varN_grad, var: body_varN    # /
grad: task1_var1_grad, var: task1_var1  # \
...                                     # --> task 1 vars and gradients
grad: task1_var1_grad, var: task1_var1  # /
grad: None, var: task2_var1             # \
...                                     # --> task 2 vars, with None gradients
grad: None, var: task2_var1             # /
```

So it looks like `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)` captures not only the sub-graph that outputs to `loss` (which can be extracted using [`tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/extract_sub_graph)), but also all trainable variables that are connected to `loss` without creating a gradient variable for them (so the returned gradient variables are `None`).

> **Question:** is such behavior normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, because [compute_gradients()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer#compute_gradients) computes gradients of `loss` with respect to a list of `tf.Variable` objects which is passed to the `var_list` parameter. If `var_list` is not provided, the function calculates gradients with respect to all variables from [GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys) collection. Also, if `loss` does not depend on certain variables, the gradients of `loss` with respect to those variables are not defined, i.e. `None` is returned. Based on the code you provided, this seems to be the case.

If you want the `optimizer` to calculate gradients with respect to certain variables only, you should make a list of such variables and pass it to the `var_list` parameter of `compute_gradients()`.

Comment: Or how about computing a list of sub-graph gradients by
`subgraph_grads_and_vars = [(g,v) for g,v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]`